# jQuery trigger keypress not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventtrigger

```
<input type="text" name="a" id="a"/>

$("#a").focus();
var e = $.Event("keypress", { which: 65, keyCode: 65 });
$("#a").trigger(e);
```

Why is this not working for me? Tried various jquery versions too.
js fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/hw48685m/3/

Comment: If possible , can describe requirement ? Thanks

Comment: the keypress is being triggered and that is not the same as setting the text of an input field to the keycode equivalent character. you will not see a capital `A` in the input field in this manner.

Comment: Ah, ok. Hmm, is there a way to type the key one letter a time using these events instead of adjusting using the .val() letter by letter.

I am asking this because I am working on a project where I have to literally key-in on a input box and only then I can trigger other events associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working.... just add the following code and test the key-press trigger.

```
$('#a').keypress(function(e){
   console.log('Yes KeyPress triggered. ' + e.which)
});
```

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks! Just like what I mentioned in the comment above, is there a way to key-in letter by letter instead of using .val() iteratively.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: `$('#a').keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which==65){
    //Your code
    }    
});`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery simulate extended library which is on Github and demo link also provided.

https://github.com/j-ulrich/jquery-simulate-ext
By this, you can easily simulate keypress keyboard event to your input field with the letter by letter inputs.